# “sudo: systemctl: command not found” when run on CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, systemctl, centos-6.6

I am using CentOS 6.6. When I try running the command

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

I get an error like this:

```
sudo: systemctl: command not found
```

As per my understanding `systemctl` is not supported in CentOS versions 6.9 and before.

Can someone please let me know what the equivalent of `systemctl` is in CentOS version 6.6?

Comment: This question would be a better fit for Unix and Linux SE

Answer (score 23):

You OS does not use `systemd` or `systemctl` but still uses `init.d` or `service` commands:

Eg:

```
sudo service {servicename} {stop|start|restart}
```

Or

```
/etc/init.d/{service} {stop|start|restart}
```

Note that even on newer systems which use `systemd`, you can generally use the `sudo service XYZ restart`syntax and it will still work.

Comment: How would I enable a service without systemctl?